# How do I disable the "stylus" mode on Ubuntu 14.04 for Touchscreen?

Tags: drivers, dell, multi-touch, touchscreen, stylus

My company is developing on a Dell 3030 AIO with Ubuntu 14.04 installed.  We have run into an Issue with the touchscreen whereby if a user rubs it with the back of their hand, the screen loses focus and finger touch stops working (freezes) until the same gesture is repeated in reverse.  Dell says that this is not the case with Windows, and their engineers state that they believe the gesture is putting the touchscreen into "stylus" mode and disables touch. The Ubuntu OS is not capable of handling this gesture. How can I get the stylus mode turned off at an OS level? What drivers are available? Is this solution even valid?